# Updating a sub-document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How do I target an subdocument in the `authors` array as shown below, in order to update it?

```
collection.update({'_id': "4f44af6a024342300e000001"}, {$set: { 'authors.?' }} )
```

The document:

```
{
    _id:     "4f44af6a024342300e000001",
    title:   "A book", 
    created: "2012-02-22T14:12:51.305Z"
    authors: [{"_id":"4f44af6a024342300e000002"}] 
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By specifying actual position of embedded document like this:

```
// update _id field of first author    
collection.update({'_id': "4f44af6a024342300e000001"}, 
                  {$set: { 'authors.0._id': "1" }} )
```

Or via [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The$positionaloperator):

```
// update _id field of first matched by _id author    
collection.update({'_id': "4f44af6a024342300e000001",
                    //you should specify query for embedded document
                    'authors._id' : "4f44af6a024342300e000002" }, 
     // you can update only one nested document matched by query                   
                    {$set: { 'authors.$._id': "1" }} )
```

Comment: there's a way to update all nested document document?

Comment: Just a note, if you want to update more than the first matching document in the collection, be sure to add {multi : true} as the third parameter to collection.update

Comment: will this insert a new sub-document if it doesnt exit?