# Updating All Nested Arrays in Mongo Object

Tags: mongodb, nosql

My data structure is:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "511D0A0EC075F3FF25000003" },
  "progresses": [
    {
      "behavior": {
        "behavior": {
          "_id": "511d052f52fbf0fd25000002",
          "disabled": false,
          "name": "Unity Installed",
          "key": "UnityInstalled",
          "points": 1,
          "timeout": 0
        },
        "key": "UnityNotInstalled",
        "name": "Unity Not Installed",
        "points": 1,
        "timeout": 0,
        "disabled": false,
        "_id": { "$oid" : "511D056552FBF0FD25000003" }
      },
      "behaviorCount": 1,
      "behaviorParameter": null,
      "userId": null,
      "modifiedAt": { "$date": 1360857614000.000000 },
      "createdAt": { "$date": 1360857614000.000000 },
      "behaviorType": "user"
    },
    {
      "behavior": {
        "behavior": {
          "_id": "511cfac4955737a01f000001",
          "disabled": false,
          "name": "test",
          "key": "tt",
          "points": 1,
          "timeout": 0
        },
        "name": "Unity Installed",
        "key": "UnityInstalled",
        "points": 1,
        "timeout": 0,
        "disabled": false,
        "_id": { "$oid" : "511D052F52FBF0FD25000002" }
      },
      "behaviorCount": 3,
      "behaviorParameter": null,
      "userId": null,
      "modifiedAt": { "$date": 1360858565000.000000 },
      "createdAt": { "$date": 1360858553000.000000 },
      "behaviorType": "user"
    },
    {
      "behavior": {
        "behavior": {
          "_id": "511d052f52fbf0fd25000002",
          "disabled": false,
          "name": "Unity Installed",
          "key": "UnityInstalled",
          "points": 1,
          "timeout": 0
        },
        "name": "Active User",
        "key": "ActiveUser",
        "points": 1,
        "timeout": 0,
        "disabled": false,
        "_id": { "$oid" : "511D058E52FBF0FD25000004" }
      },
      "behaviorCount": 1,
      "behaviorParameter": null,
      "userId": null,
      "modifiedAt": { "$date": 1360858565000.000000 },
      "createdAt": { "$date": 1360858565000.000000 },
      "behaviorType": "user"
    },
    {
      "behavior": {
        "behavior": {
          "_id": "511d058e52fbf0fd25000004",
          "disabled": false,
          "name": "Active User",
          "key": "ActiveUser",
          "points": 1,
          "timeout": 0
        },
        "name": "Invite Count",
        "key": "InviteCount",
        "points": 1,
        "timeout": 0,
        "disabled": false,
        "_id": { "$oid" : "511D061752FBF0FD25000006" }
      },
      "behaviorCount": 1,
      "behaviorParameter": null,
      "userId": null,
      "modifiedAt": { "$date": 1360858587000.000000 },
      "createdAt": { "$date": 1360858587000.000000 },
      "behaviorType": "user"
    }
  ],
  "trophyAchievements": [

  ],
  "userId": "asfasd"
}
```

I want to update all progresses.behaviorCount to 1. How can i done that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use mongo's [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#update-a-document-element-without-specifying-its-position) and dot notation.

In your case, I'd use smth like this:

```
db.test.update({}, {$set: {"progresses.$.behaviorCount": "testing"}}, { multi: true })
```

But, it won't update all fields in the nested array, just one at a time.

See similar problems:

- [MongoDB: Updating subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646798/mongodb-updating-subdocument)
- [Updating a sub-document in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401668/updating-a-sub-document-in-mongodb)

As a workaround, you can loop over nested array and update `behaviorCount` one at a time by index.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This script is the answer:

```
var i = 0;
db.users.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.progresses.forEach(function(progress) {
        progress.behaviorCount = 1;
    });

    db.users.save(doc);
    if (i % 10000 == 0) print(i);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: output: users.find(...).forEach is not a function