# MongoDB - how to update object using a field in the object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

how to update certain object using its's id in the posts array for example changing the the first object in posts using it's id

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e3929127b0a7599f0a33b90"),
"posts" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "title",
        "desc" : "body",
        "id" : ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561f4b")
    },
      {
        "title" : "title2",
        "desc" : "body2",
        "id" : ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561x2t")
    }
],
"name" : "jarvis",
"email" : "jarvis@yahoo.com",
"password" : "123",
"__v" : 0
```

}

to be something like this

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5e3929127b0a7599f0a33b90"),
"posts" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "new title",
        "desc" : "new body",
        "id" : ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561f4b")
    },
      {
        "title" : "title2",
        "desc" : "body2",
        "id" : ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561x2t")
    }
],
"name" : "jarvis",
"email" : "jarvis@yahoo.com",
"password" : "123",
"__v" : 0
```

}

Comment: You question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372065/mongodb-how-do-i-update-a-single-subelement-in-an-array-referenced-by-the-inde

Comment: Welcome, similar questions have been answered before eg. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401668/updating-a-sub-document-in-mongodb).

You can also find more about handling nested documents in MongoDB's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/).

Comment: Di you want to update always the **first** element in `post[]` or the post having `id = ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561f4b")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be this one with [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#updateone-arrayfilters)

```
db.col.updateMany(
   {},
   {
      $set: {
         "posts.$[p].title": "new title",
         "posts.$[p].desc": "new body"
      }
   },
   { arrayFilters: [{ "p.id": ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561f4b") }] }
)
```

arrayFilters have been introduced in MongoDB version 3.6

Comment: thanks a lot can you tell good resources to improve my mongodb knowledge

Comment: @YoussefMaher, open stackoverflow.com and try to answer the questions of other people. Try to find the solution just based on documentation, without google.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
yourModel.updateOne({
    "posts.id": ObjectId("5e396faeac120790c4561f4b")
}, {
    $set: {
        "posts.0.title": "new title",
        "posts.0.desc": "new body"
    }
}).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: How do you know that you always have to update element 0? The post could be at any position in array `posts[]`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "for example changing the first object in posts using it's id". That's not the universal solution, I agree. To update а specific element we need to use positional operator $.